# Disable javascript function while typing in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, function, jquery, keyboard-events

I have a photo galery with following simple function to navigate to the previous / next photo with the arrow keys on keyboard:

```
$(function() {
    var navEnabled = true;

    $(document).keyup(function(e) {
        if (navEnabled) {
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                case 37 : window.location = $('.prev').attr('href'); break;
                case 39 : window.location = $('.next').attr('href'); break;
            }
        }
    });

    $('#comment_area').bind('focus', function (event) {
        navEnabled = false;
    }).bind('blur', function (event) {
        navEnabled = true;
    });
});
```

Below each photo I have a html textarea element **(! which is loaded via AJAX while page load!)** with the id **#comment_area** to leave a comment to a photo, and I'm looking for a solution to disable the keyboard photo navigation while typing and turn on after again. The code above seems not to work, and I guess it's because the textarea element was loaded via AJAX. I tried to move the .bind function code into the AJAX request, so it will know about the #comment_area id, but then the navEnabled variable is unknown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Let me assume that the container element that you're loading the Ajax content into is called `#ajax_container`. Then you could use:

```
$('#ajax_container').on( 'focus', '#comment_area', function (event) {
    navEnabled = false;
}).on( 'blur', '#comment_area', function (event) {
    navEnabled = true;
});
```

And what version of jQuery are you using? This code is for 1.7+ and will need to be adjusted for older versions.

Answer (score 0):

How about just not binding it to that specific element using `not()`:

```
$(document).not('#comment_area').on('keyup', function(e) {
      switch(e.keyCode) {
          case 37 : window.location = $('.prev').attr('href'); break;
          case 39 : window.location = $('.next').attr('href'); break;
      }
});
```